# Sequelize finders excludes attributes but want all

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use sequelize with nodeJs.
I have a table with foreign keys but I don't know why, they doesn't appear in query.

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize"
import { sequelize } from "./config"

class VolumeRangeDiscount extends Model{
    public readonly id: number;
    public readonly updatedAt!:Date;
    public readonly createdAt!:Date;
    public discount: number;

    public static associate(models){
        VolumeRangeDiscount.belongsTo(models.VolumeRange, {
            foreignKey: "volumeRangeId",
            as: "volumeRange",
        });
        VolumeRangeDiscount.belongsTo(models.Pack, {
            foreignKey: "packId",
            as: "pack",
        });
    }
}

VolumeRangeDiscount.init({
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    discount:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
    }
    
},  { sequelize, tableName: "VolumeRangeDiscount" })



export default VolumeRangeDiscount
```

When I want to findOne by id it doesn't query foreign key columns:

```
export function findVolumeRangeDiscountById(id) {
    return VolumeRangeDiscount.findOne({ where: { id }, raw: true });
}
```

And the generated query is:

```
SELECT "id", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "discount" FROM "VolumeRangeDiscount" AS "VolumeRangeDiscount" WHERE "VolumeRangeDiscount"."id" = '3';
```

But if I add attribute option with the column name it works, they are returned.
Do you know why by default they aren't in the generated query ?

It doesn't add foreignKey in my model, VolumeRangeDiscount.rawAttributes returns:

```
 {
    id: {allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: INTEGER {
    options: {
    },
    _length: undefined,
        _zerofill: undefined,
        _decimals: undefined,
        _precision: undefined,
        _scale: undefined,
        _unsigned: undefined},
    Model: VolumeRangeDiscount,
        fieldName: 'id',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'id'
},
createdAt: {type: DATE {options: [Object], _length: ''
},
    allowNull: false,
        Model: VolumeRangeDiscount,
        fieldName: 'createdAt',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'createdAt'},
updatedAt: { type: DATE {options: [Object], _length: ''
},
    allowNull: false,
        Model: VolumeRangeDiscount,
        fieldName: 'updatedAt',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'updatedAt'},
discount: {type: INTEGER {
    options: {},
    _length: undefined,
        _zerofill: undefined,
        _decimals: undefined,
        _precision: undefined,
        _scale: undefined,
        _unsigned: undefined
},
    allowNull: true,
        Model: VolumeRangeDiscount,
        fieldName: 'discount',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'discount'},
}
```

Comment: you just have to use include function according to your code structure  as answered by @tbking

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize is an ORM and it handles the association for you. Instead of fetching the foreign key, you can use it to fetch the associated row in two ways:

1. Eager loading

   ```js
   VolumeRangeDiscount.findOne({ where: { id }, include 'VolumeRange' });
   ```

   This will populate the `VolumeRange` object with the associated row.
2. Lazy loading

   ```js
    const vrDiscount = VolumeRangeDiscount.findOne({ where: { id }, include 'VolumeRange' });
    const volumeRange = vrDiscount.getVolumeRange();
   ```

More on this can be found in the [docs here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#fetching-associations---eager-loading-vs-lazy-loading).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work because Sequelize doesn't automatically add attributes to my model (you can see my edit).